# Fragment wont work

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment

Hi i am new to android development.

I am using fragments - but i dont entirely understand how it works.

When i launch the app it crashes.

I have googled a lot but cannon solve this :(

I have an Activity(MainActivity) that must use a fragment. MainActivity looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

And the main.xml contains a ListView and a Fragment:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment class="com.todolist.NewItemFragment"
    android:id="@+id/titles_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

My fragment extends ListFragment and looks like:

```
public class NewItemFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_item_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

And the new_item_fragment.xml looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I Dont know why it crashes. I must have misunderstood something.
I hope someone out there can help - dont know what to do :)

THX

---

I have imported the library:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

And made the MainActivity class extend FragmentActivity

It gives me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Post your logCat please.

Comment: See the edit I made in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `new_item_fragment.xml` layout file like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

to solve the most obvious error. If the app still crashes then post the `Logcat` with the exception.

Also, as you're extending the `Activity` class make sure you only use the `Fragment` related classes from the SDK(not the compatibility package if you have it registered in your app). This classes are available starting from `Honeycomb`.

If you're going to use `FragmentActivity` then make sure you use the `Fragment` class from the compatibility package(from where the `FragmentActivity` comes).

Comment: Where am i going to use the Fragment class?

Comment: @user1093774 You use `ListFragment` so make sure your `NewItemFragment` class extends the `ListFragment` from the compatibility package. Check your imports.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace your fragment by follow code:

```
public class NewItemFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_item_fragment, null, false);
    }
}
```